# Version control for big binary files?

Tags: git, version-control, binaryfiles

Are there any systems of version control for large binary files like Git?

I have an opinion, that it is possible to compress binary files with small differences with a ratio, close to number of these files. Is it possible with Git or some other version control systems?

Comment: What is the big binary files? Media content? Save link or uniq-id and save checksum. It is probably for database. I use backup-like technique for that. Check this article https://www.perforce.com/blog/storing-large-binary-files-in-git-repositories

Comment: Have you searched the web for your title? I'm sure you'll find some options that way… As a user with nearly 9K reputation you should know that asking us to find or recommend an off-site resource is off-topic.

Comment: @oklas doesn't matter

Comment: @Chris I dind't find anything with required feature.

Comment: It has the matter to figure out a reason to place such files to version control system. How to compare two different version of big file and what is sence of that. Forexample word files was binary but word have option to comare. So clearcase seems recommended to put word doc under sc. If no such possibility then no reason to put it into sc. File with checksum of that files or some like thas is make sence.

Comment: @oklas I agree that solution is not trivial, this is why I am asking

Comment: May be it is not concern vcs but archiving and compact storage. If vcs take on iself task to analize new version of file for changed chunks and save only new chunks to save space it make sence. It is not quick task anyway. But is this task for vcs or it is task for archive or filesystem?

Answer (score 1):

You could use Git LFS. [**Git Large File Storage**](https://git-lfs.github.com/) (LFS) replaces large files such as audio samples, videos, datasets, and graphics with text pointers inside Git, while storing the file contents on a remote server like GitHub.com or GitHub Enterprise.

Comment: But what happen, if big file changes? How many versions of it stored?

Comment: @Dims I think the point is that all versions are stored *outside* the git repository, which means that the git repo remains small, and you only download the versions for the commits you check out.

Answer (score 1):

Git Lfs is what you need, that you can use with Github, Gitlab or Visual Studio Team Services.

Big files are not stored in the git repository, but just there ids/sha1. They are stored on the server and downloaded when doing a checkout.

All the versions are always kept. I don't know if there is some way to delete them.

Comment: on what servers the files are stored? I mean, if the metadata is stored in GitHub, or VSTS, then the actual files can't be stored there, can they?

Comment: @SaeedNeamati You can use git-lfs only on service/server supporting it and in this case, content of the file is stored on the server too but next to the repository and not inside it (but technically, I don't know where exactly. I know that VSTS store everything in a SqlServer database but I don't know how other providers do...)